# Why does the bottom BLUE NLA channel affect the upper tracks?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have been trying to learn blender animation but I am vey frustrated.
I have a NLA question. The Blue NLA CHANNEL STRIP seems to affect the upper channels even though………….
According to the BLENDER MANUAL

**Tracks are the layering system of the NLA. At its most basic level, it can help organize strips. But it also layers motion much like an image editor layers pixels – the bottom layer first, to the top, last.**

I have not found this to be the case. The bottom track seems to have an extreme effect on tracks above them. I don’t know if it is a malfunction of my install or maybe my understanding of this is function. I have included my blender file. Please see my screen shots.

Please advise. Thank You.[image: file with NOTHING extrapolation]

[image: blender 1]

[image: blender 2]

Answer (score 1):

Thoose blue "channels" are not tracks: they are a list of all animated objects in your scene, alphabetically ordered.

As they belong each to a different object, they all act in parallel.

Inside the blue "folder" are the NLA tracks (in your screenshot, in grey, they are called NLA track, NLA track.001, NLA Track 002, ......).

Theese NLA tracks follow the rule from bottom to top.

Comment: My problem is that the OBJECT BLUE CHANNEL at the bottom z1 cube is affecting the all tracks above it with location data. If I turn the hold off it affects the position of my character. My question is - is this normal behavior for blender or am I doing something wrong?

Please Advise. Thank You

Comment: Probably z1 cube is parent of something, or some constraint point at it. The animation itself is independent.

Comment: Thank You for your response. Yes the z1 cube does have constraint on it. the character is following the path of the cube. I will try to redo this without this. So according to you. there should be no interaction of the tracks if used properly. It is my misuse of the track that caused my problems. I will try this.